# Dictionary Constructor C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm having this issue creating a dictionary, have no idea what it could be.

```
Dictionary<string, string> cmd = new Dictionary<string, string>();
cmd.Add("RA0", "0");
```

I've using this and Microsoft and forums code examples, and I always get the errors below (original error messages are in spanish, I translated it for you)

> Error 1   Token '(' is not valid for a class, or struct or
>   interface member declaration
>   D:\Empresa\Freelance\pic18f2550-usb\VirtualSwitches\VirtualSwitches\Form1.cs  19  16  VirtualSwitches
>
> Error 2   'VirtualSwitches.Form1.cmd' is 'field' but it is used as a
>   'type'    D:\Empresa\Freelance\pic18f2550-usb\VirtualSwitches\VirtualSwitches\Form1.cs    19  9   VirtualSwitches

Comment: I don't see any error in your code. Can you please translate your error message to English?

Comment: Is that code inside a method?

Comment: Inside the Form class

Comment: **Where** in the `Form` class? Please post the full code.

Comment: These error messages indicate that there is a problem with either the place you are putting this code or the structure of the surrounding code.  This code itself would be fine, if it were in a method body.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error message "`cmd` is a field, but it is used like a type" tells me that you are declaring your `cmd` as a member of a class.

You cannot add items inside a declaration using `Add`, unless the declaration is inside a method.

When you declare a dictionary as a member of a class, and you wish to add some elements to it, use `{` + `}` initializer:

```
Dictionary<string, string> cmd = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"RA0", "0"}
};
```

Comment: The OP's `Add` isn't inside the declaration, though.  Copy/pasting those two lines of OP code and running them is successful.

Comment: @ThomasStringer It's definitely outside a method, because the error in Spanish says "a field is used like a type". This happens when `cmd.Add` is used outside a method.

Comment: Ah, got it.  Makes sense, now, I see your recommendation/answer.  +1!